# Disc bounded by a plane curve

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, surfaces, continuum-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be a sphere topologically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$.

> Is it always possible to find a disc $\Delta\subset\Sigma$ which is bounded by a plane curve?

It is easy to find an open disc which boundary lies in a plane,
but the boundary might be crazy; for example it might be Polish circle shown on the diagram.

[image]

**Comments**

- [A simpler question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/322332/): *Does every surface topologically embedded in the Euclidean space contains a planar arc?*
- [Curves on potatoes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/363950/) --- another closely related problem.

Comment: The title and the question don't quite match... Did you mean to say, "by a closed curve *in the plane*?"

Comment: probably rather "a closed plane curve" (i.e. contained in some plane, not a given plane)

Comment: The main body of the question still doesn't mention that the curve is supposed to be planar! Also, do you have an example of the situation in the last sentence, where the boundary doesn't contain simple curve?

Comment: @JimConant take any open disk $D$ of the plane with some weird boundary: since it is closed, there is a smooth function whose zero set is exactly $\partial D$. Then the graph of $f$ is a smooth surface with an open disk $D'$ whose boundary is $\partial D'=\partial D$, the intersection with the plane.

Comment: @PietroMajer: but such graphs can't be extended to embedded spheres in general.

Comment: what is the obstruction? It seems to me t can be included even in a smoothly embedded sphere.

Comment: @PietroMajer Consider a boundary which is a circle union a line segment. You can certainly make this the cross section of a map of a sphere, but there is pinching, so it is not embedded.

Comment: So, in some sense your question is: Could $\Sigma$ meet *every* plane in a Polish circle (or something equally "crazy").

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke "something at least as crazy", Polish circle is a very nice compared to the pseudocircle.

Comment: @JimConant: sorry, I don't follow you: why the sphere should not be embedded? it is a smooth graph there.

Comment: @PietroMajer: Okay, I see a way you could do it for the example I gave, but it is not obvious to me that it can be done in general. For my example, you could have the top part of the sphere tangent to the line segment, and then just cap it off with a hemisphere on the bottom.

Comment: ok, that was an example after your request --the sphere is part of the construction, so there is no difficulty in closing the graph with an upper hemisphere  (say that $D=\{f<0\}$ is a subset of the Euclidean disk of radius 1/3 around the origin, $\partial D=\{f=0\}$, and $f(x,y)=1-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ holds  for $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge2/3$)

Comment: @PietroMajer:  I was saying that I agree with you that the example I initially gave could be done, but it's not obvious to me that any such example could be closed off to an embedded sphere.

Comment: Every simple closed curve on the sphere bounds two discs on it, therefore your question can be phrased equivalently: "Does every sphere topologically embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ contain a planar simple closed curve?" How about a planar arc?

Comment: @WlodekKuperberg I do not know.

Comment: What if the embedding of the sphere is a diffeomorphism? It seems like it should be easier to get a positive answer in this case.  Is this known?

Comment: @DouglasSirk for diffeomorphisms it follows from Sard's theorem.

Comment: Related: There are continuous functions $f: {\mathbb R}^2\to {\mathbb R}$ such that no level set contains a nondegenerate arc. Thus, the graph of $f$ has the property that its intersection with every horizontal hyperplane contains no nondegenerate arcs.

Comment: @MoisheKohan could you give a ref, or maybe you could explain in an answer?

Comment: @MoisheKohan there is a good chance that iterating homemorphisms of the type $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,y,z+f(x,y))$ could map a plane to the needed surface.

Answer (score 5):

As requested, here is a related result:

**Theorem.** There exists a continuous (also also open) real-valued function $R^2\to R$ whose level sets are all homeomorphic to the open [pseudo-arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc). In particular, level sets contain no nondegenerate arcs.

Similarly, one can construct a continuous monotone map $S^2\to [0,1]$ such that all level sets are homeomorphic to the pseudo-circle, i.e. the unique (up to homeomorphism) hereditarily indecomposable circularly chainable continuum. Again, pseudo-circle contains no nondegenerate arcs.

The story of this theorem is rather interesting. Quoting from

*Prajs, Janusz R.*, [**A continuous circle of pseudo-arcs filling up the annulus**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-99-02330-2), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 352, No. 4, 1743-1757 (2000). [ZBL0936.54019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0936.54019).

where a proof of this theorem is given:

> Among the results obtained by Knaster during World War II one can find the following announcement, originally presented in Kiev in 1940:

> There exists a real-valued, monotone mapping from the plane that is not constant on any arc. In the construction Knaster’s hereditarily indecomposable continua were exploited. Actually, Knaster’s result can be reformulated in the following stronger version:
> There exists a real valued, monotone mapping from the plane such that all pointinverses are hereditarily indecomposable.

> Unfortunately, Knaster’s notes concerning this result were burned during the war, Knaster had never written down the result again, and even his closest exstudents do not know his original idea of construction...

> A result similar to that announced by Knaster (with higher dimensional analogues) was proved by Brown in 1958:

> M. Brown, Continuous collections of higher dimensional continua, Ph. D. Thesis, University
> of Wisconsin, 1958.

*Of course*, Brown did not publish his proof either, but Prajs finally did, see above.