# Planar arc on a topologically embedded sphere or disk in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, surfaces, continuum-theory

An *arc* is a set homeomorphic to the unit interval $[0,1]$; an arc in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is *planar* if it is contained in some plane.

The following questions are motivated by Anton Petrunin's [Disc bounded by a plane curve](https://mathoverflow.net/q/257420/36904) :

> **Question 1.** Does every topologically embedded sphere in
>   $\mathbb{R}^3$ necessarily contain a ***planar*** arc?

A negative answer to this question would immediately answer Anton's question in the negative as well.

> **Question 2.** Does every topologically embedded disk in
>   $\mathbb{R}^3$ necessarily contain a ***planar*** arc?

**Remark.** Obviously, a positive answer to Question 2 would imply the same for Question 1, but the converse is not obvious, perhaps not even true.