# Can one explore a surface along ‘piecewise planar’ curves?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology

Suppose $d\in \{3,4,\dotsc\}$ and $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is non-empty, open and connected with its complement $A^c$ connected too and $\text{int}(A^c)\neq \emptyset$. Its boundary $S:=\partial A$ is then [connected too](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170337/connectedness-of-the-boundary?noredirect=1&lq=1). Let $A^{(2)}$ be the set of 2-dimensional affine planes within the affine space $\mathbb{R}^d$.  For any $x\in S$, define
\begin{gather*}
S_x:=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_x^{(n)} \\
S_x^{(1)}:=\{y\in S\mid\exists H\in A^{(2)}\mathrel:\text{ $x$ and $y$ are in the same connected component of }H\cap S\},\\
S_x^{(n+1)}:=\{y\in S|\,\exists z\in S_x^{(n)}:\,y\in S_z^{(1)}\}.
\end{gather*}
Is $S_x=S$ for all $x \in S$? If not, is $\{S_x\mid x\in S\}$ a countable partition of $S$?

Comment: 3 related questions: https://mathoverflow.net/q/257420/ https://mathoverflow.net/q/322332/ https://mathoverflow.net/q/363950/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the set
$S=\{\,(t,t^2,t^3)\in\mathbb R^3\mid\,t\in\mathbb R\}$.
Clearly $S$ is connected, and so is its complement $A=\mathbb R^3\setminus S$.

Note that each plane has at most 3 points of intersection with $S$.
It follows that $S_x=\{x\}$ for any $x\in S$.

The only problem is the set $A^c=S=\partial A$ has empty interior, but it is easy to fix by removing from $A$ a closed ball centered at a point in $S$.

Comment: Thx! Of course, this $S$ is not the boundary of an open set. It is not a 'surface'.

Comment: TeX note: $\mathbb R^3 \setminus S$ `\mathbb R^3 \setminus S` spaces better than $\mathbb R^3 \backslash S$ `\mathbb R^3 \backslash S`.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: @ThibautDemaerel fixed now. [Sorry I read $\text{int}(A^c)= \emptyset$ insted of $\text{int}(A^c)\neq \emptyset$.]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your updated answer for a while. I realize I should better have asked a slightly different question, namely the same one except that we take $S=\partial\left(\overline{A}\right)$ ($A$ still open).

Comment: @ThibautDemaerel this version seems to be open --- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363950/curves-on-potatoes