# Curves on potatoes

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

On [twitter recently](https://twitter.com/robinhouston/status/1273396874788179968?s=20), Robin Houston brought up this problem from a [mathematical puzzle book of Peter Winkler](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/9780429062476):

[image]

The puzzle is attributed to the book ["The mathemagician and the pied piper"](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/9780429063008), and appears on p. 56 in a chapter on "Puzzles from around the world" by Richard I. Hess (so presumably this problem did not originate in this book).

The point of this question is how does one make this puzzle precisely formulated mathematically? Specifically, does it hold if one interprets "potato" to mean a compact surface embedded in $\mathbb{E}^3$ (3-dimensional Euclidean space), and "curve" to mean an embedded loop, and “identical” to mean differing by an orientation preserving isometric of $\mathbb{E}^3$?

I don't want to give any hints as to the "solution" to the puzzle, so I will leave further discussion to the comments (so don't look there if you don't want a hint).

Comment: Robin Houston's comment that "the solution is incredibly simple" is a great hint!

Comment: The most obvious mathematical interpretation of the puzzle is that the surface of the potatoes should be smoothly embedded spheres. Then one can show by transversality that there will be a translate of one potato that intersects the other in a smooth closed curve. However, this argument doesn't work in the topological case. One could imagine that the surface is an Alexander horned sphere, or even worse an Alford sphere, and that the intersections between translates might be indecomposable continua, or maybe with non-trivial $\pi_1$ but no closed embedded curve, or a topologist's sine curve.

Comment: @IanAgol Unless I am misunderstanding the constraints of the puzzle you don't necessarily need to take intersecting translates of the two surfaces. If you rotate one first and then intersect can't you avoid the bad intersections to get a closed curve? This seems possible in the horned sphere case at least.

Comment: "identical" means that there's a (positive) isometry of the ambient Euclidean space mapping the first to the second?

Comment: @YCor: yes, do you have a possible other interpretation?

Comment: @IvanMeir: Yes, it might work for a specific example, but it's not clear how to do that e.g. for an Alford sphere. https://books.google.com/books?id=Qo2DAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA91&ots=7pG0sAhVNy&dq=alford%20sphere&pg=PA89#v=onepage&q=alford%20sphere&f=false

Comment: @IanAgol Yes I do, and you certainly can imagine so. I mentioned the one I found most likely.

Comment: @ycor: what other interpretation can you think of? That would help me clarify the question if it is ambiguous.

Comment: @IanAgol for instance equal modulo possibly negative isometry, or equal modulo similarity (I've already seen "equal" to mean "the same mod positive similarity" for planar triangles).

Comment: @YCor Okay, I see what you mean. Given that the original problem as stated was ambiguous, I should try to make it more precise.

Comment: I guess one could also interpret “identical” to mean an isometry of the induced metric. For connected arcs I think this should be equivalent to an ambient isometry (but possibly orientation reversing).

Comment: Well, "smooth compact surfaces" and "embedded loop" should be enough. Just move one surface toward the other and let them intersect transversally. Probably Sard theorem is necessary at a certain point in order to formalize things, but the idea seems to work

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: Yes, it follows from Sard. Given two smooth oriented surfaces $S_1,S_2 \subset \mathbb{E}^3$, take a map $\phi: T^1S_1\times T^1S_2\to Isom^+(\mathbb{E}^3)$ which is the unique isometry $g$ taking $v_1\in T^1S_1$ to  $v_2 \in T^1S_2$, and the unit normal to unit normal. $S^1$ acts on the fibers of this map, since rotating the vectors does not affect the isometry. Hence the image of $\phi$ is $5$-dimensional in a $6$-dimensional Lie group. Any isometry $g \in Isom^+(\mathbb{E}^3)-im(\phi)$ with $g(S_1) \cap S_2\neq \emptyset$ will be transverse and hence contain a loop.

Comment: @IanAgol  A very weird potatoe :-)

Comment: Real potatoes aren't what I would call "smooth," so it would be be nice to have a topoogical version of the result. Though I've never seen an Alexander horned potato! Does it make things easier to assume that the potato is a sphere whose exterior is simply connected?

Comment: I always skip potatoes with infinite surface area at the store - they take too long to peel.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I think the problem is well-defined as given. Sorry, I didn’t know (or forgot) about your older question.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin the smooth case is easy to solve, so not an open question.